# Get smallest Int out of [Int] without using predefined functions or arithmetic operators except <=, ==,

Tags: haskell

I have the task to implement a function that returns the smallest Int out of a [Int].
For this task I'm only allowed to use [], : and comparison operators such as <=, ==, etc.
So no predefined functions or arithmetic operators are allowed.
It doesn't matter what the function returns for an empty list.

I'm a bit confused because I could not find any solution to this on google and I just started to learn Haskell because my university wants me to do this.

So what I got so far:

```
smallestInt :: [Int] -> Int
smallestInt [] = 0
smallestInt [xs] = xs
smallestInt (x:xs) = -- what to do for lists > 1 element ? --
```

Comment: Think about it - what's the smallest element of a list in terms of its head and the tail? (hint: use recursion)

Comment: *"I'm a bit confused because I could not find any solution to this on google"*: http://learnyouahaskell.com/ and http://book.realworldhaskell.org/.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations but I don't want to learn Haskell from scratch with any books. I just want to learn anything I really need to in order to pass exams.

Comment: the solution could be very similar in almost any programming language. recursion is really the basic of the basic stuff. if you could describe the answer in programmer language somebody will give you the syntax in haskell.

Comment: That worked :D I created the same function in C# using recursion and I could easily port it to Haskell. Maybe I didn't get the best solution but it works :) Thanks

Comment: @GBoehm i had only one professor who teaches me recursion via lisp and prolog. I don't think that recursion is common sense, but it should be.

Comment: in all honestly I have to say that you should further increase your knowledge elsewhere additionally because your teachings are clearly lacking. try tryruby.com ruby is a great language with a easy syntax and needed in the real world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint because I think you should figure it out, but the key idea you need to use is recursion - use `smallestInt` on `xs` first, like this

```
smallestInt (x:xs) = let possibleAnswer = smallestInt xs in
            ... -- enough hint!
```

remember you can use `<=` and `if`.

`if` works like

```
if x == 7 then "Hooray" else "OK"
```

By the way, I think you should have

```
smallestInt [] = error "An empty list doesn't have a smallest element"
```

because I think it's better to fail publicly than succeed privately with a lie like `smallestInt []` being `0`. (Later on, you'll learn a nicer solution to this kind of problem using the `Maybe` data type, where you succeed or fail publicly, but failure doesn't crash your program.)

Also I suggest

```
smallestInt [x] = x
```

because we normally use `xs` to mean a list, whereas you just mean a single element.

Comment: Ok I could not create the function using your example but after creating a similar function in another language I tried to port it to Haskell. Finally I came up with this: 
smallestNum (x:xs) = 
    if x <= smallestNum xs 
        then x 
    else smallestNum xs

Thanks for your help and your suggestions :)

Comment: @TorbenJonas Well done. Now you've solved it, I'll fill out my suggestion with where I was headed: `let possibleSolution = smallestNum xs in` `if x < possibleSolution then x else possibleSolution`